# Opening a new browser tab in client side through node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I am creating a twitter chatbot using node js and twit module.

```
T.post('statuses/update', { status: 'hello world!' }, function(err, reply) {
  //  opening a new window in client
});
```

Above code I am using for status update. After updating the status, I need to open a link in a new browser tab in the client system.

To be precise, my node application will be running on a server. When some user tweets, my application will send a reply. Along with the reply I need to send a request to open a browser tab / window in the client system from which the tweet came.

Is this possible using node js? Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.

There is no way to identify the client based on the tweet they sent, let alone connect to that client, force it to open a web browser, and then force it to open a specific URL.